# Low beams turn off when I switch to high beams?

Tags: electrical

08 Trailblazer SS. Low beams go off when I switch to high beams?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair.Your question is not clear.can you please elaborate bit more

Comment: Low beams are supposed to go off in all vehicles when switching to main beam.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: lows don't always go off... mine stay on as they are the outer ones.

Comment: Low beams stay on on my vehicle with H4 bulbs

Comment: It depends on the bulb type, design of the lighting solution as well. Low beam uses a separate bulb and high uses a separate bulb in the 2008 Chevy TB. When engaged to high, both should remain 'on'. There is an underlying cause preventing this function.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably the bulbs you are using.  Low beams should be dual filament.  If you are using single filament (or circuit for led) they will turn off.